# Cannot Buy Land in Falkreath

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I am playing Skyrim on the Xbox 360 and experiencing a ***major*** glitch.  Here is my current situation:

My character is currently at level 75 and I am Thane in the following cities:

- Winterhold
- Windhelm
- Falkreath
- Solitude
- Morthal
- Markarth
- Dawnstar
- Riften

I downloaded Hearthfire DLC around level 60 and received two notices from the courier:

1. Adoption letter
2. Letter from Steward in Falkreath about buying land

I ignored both letters and went about my business (messing up trolls and skeevers).  I eventually grew tired of that and finished the Dark Brotherhood quests.  After the last mission, I made my way back to Falkreath and talked to the steward.  But, no matter what I do, I cannot buy land from the steward! WHY!? I am holding a note that says I can buy land in Falkreath.

I even threw the note at [Nenya](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Nenya), the Jarl's incompetent steward, hoping she would realize the error of her ways, but to no avail.

I have no miscellaneous tasks left so it is not a matter of doing favors for the Jarl. My last major save was 15 levels ago and I would prefer *not* to restart the game from scratch.  Has anyone else experienced this? Any suggestions on what to do??

Comment: I have only one question. Do you have the hearthfire add-on. If you dont then you cant buy land. if you do then you shouldn't be having any problems.

Comment: @JasonEspinoza yes I downloaded it around level 60.

Comment: If you joined the Dark Brotherhood, did you kill Helvard or not?

Comment: @Jim I killed Helvard. If you check the answer I provided below, I go into more detail. If you don't kill Helvard, then you should be good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After doing some digging:

- http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=386051
- http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-/63954526

It turns out the glitch is caused by completing the Dark Brotherhood quest - Kill Helvard.

Apparently, the [Jarl of Falkreath](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Siddgeir) ***knows*** you killed Helvard *(even if you are sneaky about it)*. In fact, I killed Helvard when he was taking a nap, so Helvard certainly didn't see it coming.

Anyway, after killing the Jarl's housecarl, Siddgeir's disposition is lowered significantly. Since I am already Thane in Falkreath, there is no way to raise his disposition, unless I was playing the game on PC.

However, I fortunately found a solution!  If you have ***NOT*** completed any of the Legion/Stormcloak quests, then make sure to do the following:

- Side with the Stormcloaks so [Dengeir](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dengeir_of_Stuhn) replaces [Siddgeir](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Siddgeir) as Jarl.
- Talk with Jarl Dengeir (he will ask you to become Thane again)
- Talk with [Tekla](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Tekla), the newly appointed steward, and she will give you the option to buy land

I really hope this helps someone in the future!