# Problem with buying land

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

How do I buy land in Skyrim?

I have become Thane of all three holds. But I still can not purchase land.

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question- do you have the Hearthfire dlc activated?

Answer (score 2):

You can technically buy land in almost all of the holds after you have become thane. You get to purchase a house.

But I will assume that you have the Skyrim Hearthfire DLC downloaded and installed and loaded into your current game.

You need to do quests for the hold to be helpful to the people in the hold aka the path to become the thane.

After that you should be able to buy the land in that hold. You need to talk to the Jarls steward and ask them to purchase the land.

There are a couple of bugs with purchasing the plots of land.

- If you are already thane in the holds and then you purchase the DLC, sometimes it will bug out and not let you buy land
- Also this [Cannot Buy Land in Falkreath](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120898/cannot-buy-land-in-falkreath)
- Also if you kill certain people in the holds or the Jarls somehow know you've killed in their hold might also affect your ability to purchase land
- Also certain dark brotherhood quests will affect your ability to purchase the land,